# android add checkbox dynamically

Tags: android, checkbox

The following are my layout xmls. Now we are have a limited number (seven) of check boxes in the layout (listitem.xml). And we are adding it in a linear layout.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
   >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:text="TESTER : "
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/tester_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:capitalize="characters" 
            android:textColor="#000000">

            <requestFocus />
        </AutoCompleteTextView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="APPS TO TEST : "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:textColor="#000000"/>




    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:background="#CCCCCC" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/apps_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view1" 
        android:dividerHeight="5dp">
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/refreshBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Refresh" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

listitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="70"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/launch_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:text="LAUNCH" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/status_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/pass_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="PASS"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/fail_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FAIL"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/failure_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="FAILURE REASONS"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/failure_reasonslist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/failure_Sound"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/failure_GPS"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/failure_Display"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/failure_Network"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/failure_Rotation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/failure_Microphone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/failure_Others"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lineatlayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DESCRIPTION : "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/description_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textColor="#000000" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lineatlayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="  SUBMIT " />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/uninstall_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="UNINSTALL" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- </RelativeLayout> -->

</LinearLayout>
```

But as per the new requirement we need to add the check boxes dynamically. Like need to fetch the options from the API call and convert it as check boxes in the view. I spent lots of time in it. Can someone suggest a method to solve this.

Our layout should be like this. In a list view we are displaying employee details and for each employee record the qualification should be loaded from the API call or database.

```
      [Reviewer Name (Editable)]       
               Employee Lest           
---------------------------------------
Employee1                    [Click Me]

Male (0)          Female ( )
Salary : [5999 (editable)]
Qualification
[X]BA
[ ]BSc
[ ]Matriculation
[ ]Other
[Submit Button]
---------------------------------------
Employee2                    [Click Me]

Male (0)          Female ( )
Salary : [5999 (editable)]
Qualification
[X]BA
[ ]BSc
[ ]Matriculation
[ ]Other
[Submit Button]
---------------------------------------
Employee3                    [Click Me]

Male (0)          Female ( )
Salary : [5999 (editable)]
Qualification
[X]BA
[ ]BSc
[ ]Matriculation
[ ]Other
[Submit Button]
---------------------------------------
```

Source code

```
private class ListAdapters extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationBean> {
    private ArrayList<ApplicationBean> items;
    private int position;

    public ListAdapters(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<ApplicationBean> mTitleList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, mTitleList);
        this.items = mTitleList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        this.position = position;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.applicationlistitem, null);
        }

        final ApplicationBean o = (ApplicationBean) items.get(position);

        if (o != null) {

            txtAppName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
            txtAppName.setText("" + o.getAppName());
            launchButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.launch_btn);
            launchButton.setTag(position);
            launchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    final PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
                    Intent LaunchIntent = pm
                            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(items
                                    .get(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag()
                                            .toString())).getPname());
                    mContext.startActivity(LaunchIntent);

                }
            });
            final LinearLayout failure_reasonslist = (LinearLayout) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.failure_reasonslist);

            rdgPassFail = (RadioGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.status_group);
            rdgPassFail.setTag(position);

            RadioButton passBtn = (RadioButton) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.pass_btn);
            passBtn.setTag(position);
            RadioButton failbtn = (RadioButton) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.fail_btn);
            failbtn.setTag(position);

            rdgPassFail
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group,
                                int checkedId) {
                            ApplicationBean o = (ApplicationBean) items
                                    .get(Integer.parseInt(group.getTag()
                                            .toString()));

                            switch (checkedId) {
                            case R.id.fail_btn:
                                Log.e("Fail button", "Clicked");
                                o.setFailState(true);
                                o.setPassState(false);
                                numOptions = 0;
                                Log.e("Fail button--1", "Clicked");

                                break;
                            case R.id.pass_btn:
                                Log.e("Pass button", "Clicked");

                                o.setFailState(false);
                                o.setPassState(true);
                                Log.e("Pass button-----1", "Clicked");

                                break;
                            }
                            items.set(Integer.parseInt(group.getTag()
                                    .toString()), o);
                        }

                    });

            LinearLayout featuresTable = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.failure_reasonslist);

            // use loop CheckBox feature1 = new CheckBox(this); 
            for(int i = 0; i<=5; i++) {
                CheckBox feature1 = new CheckBox(this.getContext());
                featuresTable.addView(feature1);
            }




            txtDescription = (EditText) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.description_text);
            txtDescription.setTag(position);
            if (txtDescription.isFocused()) {
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) mContext
                        .getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputManager.restartInput(txtDescription);
            }

            txtDescription
                    .setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                            if (!hasFocus) {

                                final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                                o.setDescription(Caption.getText()
                                        .toString());

                            }

                        }
                    });
            uninstallButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.uninstall_btn);
            uninstallButton.setTag(position);
            // uninstallButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            o.setUninstallVisible(false);
            uninstallButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Uri packageUri = Uri.parse("package:"
                            + items.get(
                                    Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString()))
                                    .getPname());
                    Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageUri);
                    uninstallIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(uninstallIntent);
                    mTitleList.remove(items.get((Integer) v.getTag()));

                    mListView.setAdapter(new ListAdapters(mContext,
                            R.id.app_name, mTitleList));
                    ((BaseAdapter) mListView.getAdapter())
                            .notifyDataSetChanged();
                    isUninstallclicked = true;

                }
            });

            submitButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);
            submitButton.setTag(txtDescription);
            submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    EditText tv = (EditText) v.getTag(); // get edittext
                                                            // object

                    txtDescription = tv;
                    if (txtTesterName.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        showDialog("Please enter the name of tester",
                                mContext);
                    } else if (numOptions == 0) {
                        showDialog("Please select failure reason", mContext);
                    } else if (tv.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        showDialog("Please enter the description", mContext);
                    } else if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {

                        showDialog(
                                "No network connection.Report won't be submitted",
                                mContext);
                    } else {

                        if (!o.isUninstallVisible()) {
                            uninstallButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            o.setUninstallVisible(true);
                            mListView.invalidate();
                        }
                        PostRequest p = new PostRequest(Integer.parseInt(tv
                                .getTag().toString()));
                        p.execute();

                    }
                }

            });

        }
        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
LinearLayout featuresTable = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.failure_reasonslist);
// use loop 
CheckBox feature1 = new CheckBox(this);
featuresTable.addView(feature1 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried this way. LinearLayout featuresTable = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.failure_reasonslist); for(int i = 0; i<=5; i++) { CheckBox feature1 = new CheckBox(this.getContext()); featuresTable.addView(feature1); } But for the first row it is created more than 6 check boxes. And 2nd row and other rows the number of check boxes are 6. But when I scroll back the check box numbers are increasing. Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

**Add CheckBox Dynamically**

```
LinearLayout my_layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
// Add Checkbox Dynamically
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(mContext);
checkBox.setText(ETnewcheckbox.getText().toString()+""); 
checkBox.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        String msg = "You have " + (isChecked ? "checked" : "unchecked") + " this Check it Checkbox.";
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
}); 

// Add Checkbox to LinearLayout 
if (my_layout != null) { 
    my_layout.addView(checkBox); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 LinearLayout lLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourMainLayout);
 CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);   // Here you will create CheckBox as many number of Checkbox you want.

 lLayout.addView(checkBox); // Here you have to add this CheckBox to your layout.
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried this way. LinearLayout featuresTable = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.failure_reasonslist); for(int i = 0; i<=5; i++) { CheckBox feature1 = new CheckBox(this.getContext()); featuresTable.addView(feature1); } But for the first row it is created more than 6 check boxes. And 2nd row and other rows the number of check boxes are 6. But when I scroll back the check box numbers are increasing. Any clue?

Comment: Can you post your code so that i can checkout something from it.

Comment: I have edited my question and posted my source code. Could you please check?

Comment: See what is happening with you is you have set your counter from 0 hence 6 checkbox are created.I am not getting what do u mean by scrollback (Either you want to say from moving from current activity to another activity and come back to current activity or anything else)

Comment: I have may rows in my view. So first row will be displayed first. In first row 6 check boxes. And then I can scroll down to see the next rows in my list view. Now there is also 6 check boxes. But when I scroll up to first row from below row positions, the check box numbers are increasing. That is what I meant.