# Dynamic Check Box Creation,text wrapping not working

Tags: android

I am created checkboxes dynamically,but the text of the checkboxes do not get wrapped to the nextline,i have set the layout params as wrap content for both width and height.

Answer (score 1):

On a button click you can generate checkbox like this code:-

```
    final LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL)


 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                CheckBox chkbx = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
                chbx.setText("I'm dynamic CheckBox!");
                linearLayout.addView(chkbx);
            }
        }
    });
```

for more detail You can visit this thread:- [linkOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618553/how-to-add-checkboxes-dynamically-in-android) and [linkTwo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189874/android-add-checkbox-dynamically)