# i addedd imageviews dynamically to horizontal scrollView but newer image comes at last

Tags: java, android, xml

I addedd ImageViews dynamically to horizontal ScrollView but newer image comes at last,is there any way the new image comes is occur at first place inside horizontal scroll view.
As you will see in my output the "black background" image i addedd recently but it occurs last in the image view.

[My Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhp5r.png)

MainActivity.java

```
 public void setimage(String imagePath) {
    final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(220, 220));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);


    ids[i] = g;
    imageView.setId(ids[i]);

    arr[j] = imageView.getDrawable().toString();
    linearLayout2.addView(imageView);

    img1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    img1.setImageDrawable(imageView.getDrawable());


    k = i;
    i++;
    j++;
    g++;

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            for (int l = 1; l <= k; l++) {


                if (v.getId() == ids[l]) {

                    ImageView imag = (ImageView) findViewById(ids[l]);
                    imag.getDrawable();
                    if (imag.getDrawable().toString() == (arr[l])) ;
                    {
                        img1.setImageDrawable(imag.getDrawable());
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    });
   }
```

Comment: @MikeM.i have question how is it popssible if i longpress any image view checkbox should appear on each image view inside horizontal scroll view?

Answer (score 0):

```
addView(view):
```

Adds a child view at the bottom by default, to add a `childView` at  a specific position use:

```
addView(View child, int index)
```

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html).

Comment: .i have question how is it popssible if i longpress any image view checkbox should appear on each image view inside horizontal scroll view?

Comment: this is irrelevant, anyway checkout this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189874/android-add-checkbox-dynamically